# How to update a pushed Fire Base object

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Pushed firebase objects are hidden behind a unique key, making referencing a pushed object difficult unless your using `childAdded`. And a reference is needed if you want to use `update` on the object.

```
{
    "ideaCount" : 0,
    "ideas" : {
        "-KNVuaB6ZaRCLmH0q8ic" : {
            "idea" : {
                "likes" : 0,
                "name" : "test"
            }
        },
        //unique key, every idea will have a new one of these
        "-KNVucJEgZxz_N0P8bcv" : {
            //want to reference this
            "idea" : { 
            "likes" : 0,
            "name" : "jkl"
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to update that "idea" object without explicitly putting that unique key in the reference?

Can I start the reference after the unique key? From my experience you need to start the reference at the root.

To be more specific, I would like to be able to change the "likes" number up and down on button press and `update` seemed to be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply answer your question, **no**. You will need the push key to complete the reference to `ideas/some-idea/likes`. However, I am assuming your are listing these "ideas" so people can like them in which you will always have the push key available. For example:

*JavaScript*

```
var theIdeas= [];
var ref = firebase.database().ref("ideas");
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        // Push key
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        // childData will be the actual contents of the child
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        });
        theIdeas.push(childData);
}, function(error) {

});
```

*AngularJS*

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("ideas");
var ideas = $firebaseArray(ref);

<!-- Push key is stored inside $id -->
<div ng-repeat"i in ideas"> {{i.$id}} </div>
```

Do whatever you wish when you receive that information. The point is that if you have grabbed an "idea" then you **do know** what the push key is and should be able to use it has part of your reference.

References:

[Firebase | key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key)